# mix.copyDirectory is not a function in Laravel Elixir 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

According [to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#copying-files-and-directories), in order to maintain the directory's structure I should use `copyDirectory` but I obtain the following:

```
/webpack.mix.js:16
   .copyDirectory('resources/assets/bower', 'public/js');
    ^

TypeError: mix.js(...).sass(...).copyDirectory is not a function
```

This is my webpack file:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .copyDirectory('resources/assets/bower', 'public/js');
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Nevermid, the docs aren't correct: you should pass **false** to the copy funcion, as follows:

```
mix.copy('resources/assets/bower', 'public/js', false);
```

This way it won't flatten the source directory

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error message.

```
TypeError: mix.copyDirectory is not a function
```

Actually, it's because you were using an old version of Laravel mix that does not support the `mix.copyDirectory`.

All you have to do is:

```
npm install laravel-mix@^1.0 --save-dev
npm run dev
```